# Boolean in URL query

Tags: php

So I'm having problems figuring this out. When i have `exemple.com/index.php?x=true`, will the value of x with `$_GET["x"]` be `"true"` as a String or `true` as a Boolean.

Comment: It will be a string. You should just use truthy/falsey values (E.G `1` and `0` respectively)

Comment: All values from `$_GET[]`, `$_POST[]` and `$_REQUEST[]` are strings. PHP only parses the request and put the pieces there, it's your task to interpret them as you want.

Comment: I personally would never use `true` or `false` as a value in a `$_GET` request.. instead just a integer `1` or `0` or yes/no etc